# Прокрутка к началу страницы после загрузки

Tags: html, jquery, css

Не могу понять, как сделать так, что при переходе по ссылке, открывалась другая страница и именно на ней отрабатывался скрипт скролла к началу страницы

https://codepen.io/st-iv/pen/XBgVWe?editors=1010

```
$('.buy').click(function(){
  $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 0},500);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Кросс-браузер, чистое решение для JavaScript:

```js
document.body.scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
```

Возможно, вы можете добавить пустой якорь в начало страницы:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(function() {
   $('<a name="top"/>').insertBefore($('body').children().eq(0));
   window.location.hash = 'top';
});
</script>
```